# How to resolve TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_core.pathUtils.urlToPathAndParams') in React-Native

Tags: react-native

My app was running perfectly but when I pull data from the git repository, I got this error.
I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error. Please help to get rid of this error and explain to me about this error.

[The error is TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_core.pathUtils.urlToPathAndParams')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl2B2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many time this method but got this error
I delete the node_modules and package-lock.json file and run `npm install` in terminal but error didn't remove.

The second method:

Then I did some similar steps

I run these commands:

```
 rm -rf node_modules/
    yarn install
    yarn start --reset-cache
```

Now the error is gone.
try this one ( second method ) if you also getting these types of error.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to install `@react-navigation/native`.

Comment: needed this to migrate from expo 40 to expo 42 using react navigation 4.

Comment: I needed this as well, this was a real life saver as there was nothing obvious to me about the errors origin

Comment: It worked, I was upgrading from expo sdk 40 to 41 and installing @react-navigation/native worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error occur because of

```
in your pull request you might be get some new npm in your
package.json file. so try to do npm install 

or 

try to remove node_modules and package-lock.json file 
do npm install might be solve your problem
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

In my case, the reason is that I did not have `@react-navigation/core` at first, then I installed `@react-navigation/core` at the newest version, which is not compatible with my old `@react-navigation/native`.
After I updated my `@react-navigation/native` to have the same version with `@react-navigation/core`, the problem is solved.

You may want to check the versions of your `@react-navigation` components to see if they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the installed packages

```
npm ls --depth=0
```

Install `@react-navigation/native` if you missing this package.